# Сделать полный перебор массива символов

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Даны три числа: a,b,c и массив символов, длина которого не больше 1000; Необходимо перебрать все возможные случаи, чтобы эти три числа составляли данный массив символов. Эти числа идут по порядку. Соответственно a,b,c будут тоже массивами символов.

Например:
 Дано 120234
Возможные случаи:
a - 1 b - 20 c - 234.
a - 1 b - 202 c - 34.
a - 1 b - 2023 c - 4.
a - 12 b - 0 c - 234.
и тд.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: Массив собирается из трех, т.е. ваша задача сводится к нахождению 2х границ между ними (2 границы заведомо определены). Запускаем 2 вложенных цикла: i = 0..len и в нем j = i..len, тут могут быть вариации в зависимости от того, могут ли массивы быть пустыми или должны содержать хотя бы один элемент. Далее всё просто, берем срезы: a = s[0, i], b = [i, j], c = [j, len]

Answer (score 0):

Просто разбить длину на 3 числа - длины подстрок.

```
string s = "1353121312"s;
for(int la = 1; la < s.length()-1; ++la) {
    for(int lb = 1; lb < s.length()-la; ++lb) {
        int lc = s.length() - la - lb;
        cout << s.substr(0,la) << " " << s.substr(la,lb) << " " << s.substr(la+lb) << endl;
        }
    }
}
```